# R: Bootstrap Percent Difference only when A > B

Tags: r, for-loop, bootstrapping

I have two sets of numbers A and B. I would like to do a bootstrap analysis where I calculate the percent difference between the values in each group but only for cases where a value in group A > B.

I've tried to code below but all the values I get are 0. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

```
A <- c(13,5,8,1,23,4,7,2,14,27)
B <- c(5,7,0.5,10, 1,3, 0.7,2,0.8,4)

percentage_difference <- function(value, value_two) {   
  (value - value_two) / value
}  

n <- 10000 
Per_Dif <- numeric(n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  if(A > B){Per_Dif[i] <- percentage_difference(sample(A, replace = T), sample(B, replace = T))}    
}
```

Comment: What does your condition $A>B$ mean? You draw a random sample from A and B, and then match only those that satistfy the condition? It sounds like a very convoluted approach, isn't it equivalent to calculate all the percentage differences, and remove the negative ones?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to draw a random sample from A and B and then only match those that satisfy the condition. I reason I took this convoluted approach was because I wanted to final n to be 10,000. And if I do the same operation to a different set of data I'd like to compare the 10,000 elements from group 1 to the 10,000 elements from group 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```r
do.call(c,lapply(1:n, function(boot){
  a <- sample(A, replace = T)
  b <- sample(B, replace = T)
  percentage_difference(a,b)[a>b]
}))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. The mean and distribution that I get using your solution seems to make buts the number of elements I get is approximately 77,000? Since n = 10,000 I thought the number of elements would be 10,000. Do you know why the number of elements in 77,000 using your method?

Comment: @SM87 The sample function is selecting a vector of the same length as A with replacement, so the number of elements you get should depend on the distributions of A and B. If you want to select only one element from the random draw, specify instead ``sample(A, size =1)``, then ``replace= T`` is redundant. If I understood the question correctly, that is

Comment: But the size of the final list will still depend on the condition ``A > B``. If you want to keep drawing until the element size is 10000, this would probably require a ``while`` loop instead.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.